# Bootstrap navbar collapse menu not working with Turbolinks

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, turbolinks

Bootstrap navbar collapse menu not working with Turbolinks.

**Working scenario**

1. On page load

   ```html
   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> </button>
   <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="menu"> </div>
   ```
2. Click menu and dropdown

   ```html
   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> </button>
   <div class="navbar-collapse in" id="menu" style="height: auto;"> </div>
   ```
3. Click menu again and collapse

   ```html
   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> </button>
   <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="menu" style="height: 1px;"> </div>
   ```

**Not working (after navigating to any page)**

1. On page load

   ```html
   the same html, no need to repeat
   ```
2. Click menu and dropdown

   ```html
   the same html, no need to repeat
   ```
3. Click menu again and collapse

   3.1. Transient change observed in the debugger

   ```html
       <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> </button>

       <div class="navbar-collapsing" id="menu" style="height: 96px;"> </div>
   ```

   Note: **class="navbar-collapsing"** and **height: 96px;**

   3.2. And then go back to the same state

   ```html
       <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> </button>
       <div class="navbar-collapse in" id="menu" style="height: auto;"> </div>
   ```

   Note: Same html as in step 2.

Libs versions:

- Turbolinks 2.1.0
- JQuery     2.0.3
- Bootstrap  3.0.3

I hope someone can come up with a real answer or an explanation.

Comment: Same issue with me, after playing around for some time figured out disabling is the best. But been able to have Turbo links will be cool.

Comment: any updates on this issue ?

Comment: I don't use Turbo links at all, I'm doing single page apps.

Answer (score 4):

The responsible here is Turbolinks. And the workaround is to not load the Turbolinks javascript.

In the file

`app/assets/javascripts/application.js`

Delete this line

`//= require turbolinks`

Comment: Also remove "data-turbolinks-track" => true from javascript_include_tag.

Answer (score 2):

Dirty Solution will be to put the following in your `application.js`

```
  $(document).on("page:change", function() {
     $(".navbar .dropdown").hover((function() {
         $(this).find(".dropdown-menu").first().stop(true, true).delay(150).slideDown();
    }), function() {
         $(this).find(".dropdown-menu").first().stop(true, true).delay(50).slideUp();
    });
  });
```

Mind that it is `change` not `load`

Answer (score 1):

Other solution.

Making permanent element. With jQuery open or close the dropdown.

```html
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" id="button-dropdown" data-turbolinks-permanent> Button</button>
```

Doc from Turbolinks
https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#persisting-elements-across-page-loads

Answer (score 0):

Add this on your headers.

```html
<meta name="turbolinks-visit-control" content="reload">
```